# Edit and delete uploaded images code inside script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am Displaying mask images & allowing user to upload the custome image inside mask image, now i want to give an option for user to Edit & Delete the Uploaded image....

Video link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/158RCO_NaXUg9KWOKSX6_SQ5r0CYF40oK/view

For that I need to create Pop up box once user click on Edit button, Also in the pop up i need to give an option to zoom, rotate the uploaded images....

for these  i need to add lot of html code in future inside jquery, so is this is good way ? because i dont want to right more html code inside jquery as it looks bad when reading....

```
                    $("<span class=\"pip\">" +                    
                    "<br/><span id="open" class=\"edit\">Edit </span>" +
                    "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove </span>" +
                    "</span>").insertAfter("#fileup");
```

Or Is it possible to write Html code outside script ?

Here is full code in pen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/drLwVO

Here is jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/86Leb4gw/3/

```js
var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {
  "path" : " newyear collage\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "newyear collage",
    "date" : "sRGB",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "newyear collage",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "height" : 612,
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 612,
          "shapeType" : "rectangle",
          "type" : "shape",
          "name" : "bg_rectangle"
        },
        {
          "x" : 160,
          "height" : 296,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 296,
              "src" : "ax0HVTs.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 429,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 188,
              "y" : 122,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 291,
          "width" : 429,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 25,
          "height" : 324,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 324,
              "src" : "hEM2kEP.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 471,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_2"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 209,
              "y" : 136,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse_2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 22,
          "width" : 471,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 612,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "newyearcollage08"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    // upload image onclick

    $('.container').click(function(e) {
  // filtering out non-canvas clicks
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'CANVAS') return;

  // getting absolute points relative to container
  const absX = e.offsetX + e.target.parentNode.offsetLeft + e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
  const absY = e.offsetY + e.target.parentNode.offsetTop + e.currentTarget.offsetTop;

  const $canvasList = $(this).find('canvas');
  // moving all canvas parents on the same z-index
  $canvasList.parent().css({zIndex: 0});

  $canvasList.filter(function () { // filtering only applicable canvases
    const bbox = this.getBoundingClientRect()
    return (
      absX >= bbox.left && absX <= bbox.left + bbox.width &&
      absY >= bbox.top && absY <= bbox.top + bbox.height)
  }).each(function () { // checking white in a click position
    const x = absX - this.parentNode.offsetLeft - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
    const y = absY - this.parentNode.offsetTop - e.currentTarget.offsetTop;
    const pixel = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    if (pixel[3] === 255) {
      $(this).parent().css({zIndex: 2})
      target = this.id;
      console.log(target);
      setTimeout(() => {
        $('#fileup').click();
      }, 20);
    }
  })
});
 
 
    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
     name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
      name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
       name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

     function json(data)

        {
            var width = 0;
            var height = 0;

            let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

            let layer1 = data.layers;
            width = layer1[0].width;
            height = layer1[0].height;
            let counter = 0;
            let table = [];

            for (let {
                    src,
                    x,
                    y,
     name
                } of arr) {
                $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
                if(name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1){
                    var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;
                }else{
                    var imageUrl1 = '';
                }    
                var mask = $(".container").mask({                
        imageUrl: imageUrl1,     
                    maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                    onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                        img.css({
                            "position": "absolute",
                            "left": x + "px",
                            "top": y + "px"
                        });

                    },
                    id: counter
                });
                table.push(mask);
                fileup.onchange = function() {

                    let mask2 = table[target];
                    mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                    document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";
     
     // Below code to Remove image

                $("<span class=\"pip\">" +                    
     "<br/><span id=\"myBtn\" class=\"edit\">Edit </span>" +
                    "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove </span>" +
                    "</span>").insertAfter("#fileup");

                $(".remove").click(function() {
                    $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
                });

                // Remove image code ended here.... 
             
                };
                counter++;
    // get the text
    
            }
drawText(data);
        }

json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready


// extempl code - get the text

const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

function drawText(layer) {

    if (layer.type === 'image') return;

    if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
        return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
    }

    if (layer.type === 'text') {
        const url = 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + layer.src;

        if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
            fonts.push(url);
            $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
                "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
                "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
                "}");
        }

$('.container').append(
            '<div class="txtContainer" ' +
            'style="' +
   'text-align: ' + layer.justification + '; ' +
   'font-family: ' + layer.font + '; ' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
   'width:' + layer.width + 'px; ' +
            'color: ' + layer.color.replace(/^0x/, '#') + '; ' +      
            'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
             'height:' + layer.height + 'px;' +
            '">' +
            layer.text +
            '</div>');
    }

}
// extempl code end 

// jq plugin 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

                $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
                container.selected(evt);
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                var img = new Image();
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');

            }
        };

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {

            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
                if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                    if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                        var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                        var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                        if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                            return; // position has not changed
                        settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                        settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                        prevX = evt.clientX;
                        prevY = evt.clientY;
                        clearTimeout(timeout);
                        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                            container.updateStyle();
                            renderInnerImage();
                        }, 20);
                    }
                } else {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function()
                {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };

        function renderInnerImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            img.src = settings.imageUrl;
            img.onload = function() {
                settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                initImage = false;
            };
        }

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
             console.log("load");
            //if (img)
               // img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
        };

        // change the masked Image
         container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {}

.container {
 background: gold;
  position: relative;
 
}

.container img {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:250px;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   margin:auto;
   z-index:999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: relative;
}

.txtContainer{ position:absolute;  text-align:center; color:#FFF}

.pip {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.remove {
  display: block;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.remove:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
.edit {
  display: block;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.edit:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: What does this code do? Please tell us. See [ask].

Comment: What is your requirement? and what you are trying to do from business/exercise point of view in this code? Your title is vague and therefore your question becomes harder to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your Templates as plain HTML (invisible) and then clone, adapt and insert them as you want.

HTML5 has even an extra template tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

````html
<div id='demoTemplate' style='display: none;'>
 <span class='pip'>                    
  <br/><span class='edit'>Edit </span>
  <br/><span class='remove'>Remove </span>
 </span>
</div>
<!-- or -->
<template id='demoTemplate'>
 <span class='pip'>                    
  <br/><span class='edit'>Edit </span>
  <br/><span class='remove'>Remove </span>
 </span>
</template>
<input id='fileup' name='fileup' type='file' style='display:none'>

<script>
  // This copies also div-style='display:none', either remove the style or the outer div/template
  $('#demoTemplate').clone().insertAfter('#fileup');

  // or even something like this
  $($('#demoTemplate').html()).insertAfter('#fileup');
</script>
```
````

Comment: thanks, instead of writing as template, is there any other way i can write the html code outside <Script> tag & still make it work for `editing & deleting uploaded images`?

Comment: can we still use same concept if we have css styles as in this code : https://pastebin.com/EextDCzF , here i included that code in codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/axdgJR

Comment: also can we use same concept if i have code like this : `"<br/><span style =\"left:  layer.x + 'px;'\" class=\"edit\" >Edit </span>" +` , because i have `left:  layer.x + 'px;`  , as  in html <style> : `left:layer.x` will not work..... how to handle these cases , how to write in better way ?

Comment: how to handle these [kind of things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55684184/using-template-tag-to-display-popup-next-to-edit-button) ?